# Is a 4000W line voltage thermostat sufficient here?

Tags: electrical, thermostat

I want to upgrade a baseboard electric thermostat to a programmable. The existing digital, non-programmable thermostat is rated for 22A (5280W) (made by PSG). The only programmables I can find max out at 16.7A/4000W.

The base boards are 2 units wired in parallel from one feed wire. They are rated for 8.3A/2000W (Marley 2548). The circuit is wired with #12 wire, 20A breaker.

It seems a 16.7A/4000W thermostat is fine. I'm just wondering if the higher rating of the original thermostat indicates anything to be concerned about, or was just a choice of the original installer for other reasons.

Comment: Are they *really* connected in series?

Comment: Yes - mounted end-to end. I pulled the connection panel to verify.

Comment: Wait - I may be assuming the series connection since the wires come out of the end of one unit and into the other. Need to check.

Comment: OK - they're in parallel. Obviously, series would be wrong. Updated question.

Comment: Or you could add a 24V transformer and relays, and use any smart stat on the market.

Comment: The spec sheet for the Marley unit says to use a 30A breaker and 10 awg wire for anything 16.1A and above. You'd probably want a similar margin for the thermostat. Keep in mind that when first turning on the heater, you'll get a slight current surge.

Comment: This is 240 volts, right?

Comment: Yes  - 240 volts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well according to the math it will work.  I would like to see a little more of a safety factor. My feelings aside, the manufacturer rates their product to handle your situation.  I would go ahead. I suspect the manufacturer has built in some safety factor. Be especially careful to ensure all connections are clean and tight.